# REST API correct error handling

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, exception

I'm migrating a bunch of xmlrpc API code from magento1 to the rest API in magento two, and was wondering if anyone knew the correct way to return API errors. Previously we would've been throwing a Mage_Api_Exception, but I haven't been able to find the matching magento 2 classes

Comment: Any solution for this question?

Comment: @SunilKumar I never got a conclusive answer but I think generally speaking you want to throw a `LocalizedException` or something that subclasses it. Hope that helps